# How to stop the download of banned dependencies in maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have added the banned dependency in the pom.xml. Though it successfully detect the banned dependencies but it's still downloading the banned dependencies.

How can I cancel the download of the banned dependencies.
Here's my code.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-maven</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <bannedDependencies>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:(,2.17.0)</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <includes>
                <!--Allowed-->
              </includes>
            </bannedDependencies>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

[image]

Comment: First is to upgrade to most recent version of the enforce plugin second you should check where it is defined as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The enforcer plugin (like any other plugin) runs **after** the downloads have happened.

Therefore, the enforcer plugin cannot stop the download from happening.